# imperva WAF rules blocked drupal 7 form submit

Tags: drupal-7, web-application-firewall, imperva

We have created a variable form using hook_variable_info where a field type "text_format".
Where we are putting a html template data. But when we are going to submit that form getting blocked by imperva.
At imperva console we are getting cross site scripting error. If anyone faced similar kind of issue, kindly support me.